# How to populate a Map from a file using 2 regex simultaneously?

Tags: java, regex, list

I'm currently populating a List from a .audit file and extracting out two pieces of information into a Map. Here is what the file looks like:

```
   type         : REGISTRY_SETTING
   description  : "1.9.56 Network security: Do not store LAN Manager hash value on next password change: Enabled"
   info         : "This control defines whether the LAN Manager (LM) hash value for the new password is stored when the password is changed."
   solution     : "Make sure 'Do not store LAN Manager hash value on next password change' is Enabled."
   reference    : "PCI-DSS|8.4,800-53|AC-3,800-53|SC-5,800-53|CM-7,800-53|CM-6,CCE|CCE-8937-5"
   see_also     : "https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/windows/CIS_Microsoft_Windows_7_Benchmark_v1.2.0.pdf"
   value_type   : POLICY_DWORD
   reg_key      : "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa"
   reg_item     : "NoLMHash"
   value_data   : 1



   type         : REGISTRY_SETTING
   description  : "1.13.3 Notify antivirus programs when opening attachments: Enabled"
   info         : "This control defines whether antivirus program to be notified when opening attachments."
   solution     : "Make sure 'Notify antivirus programs when opening attachments' is Enabled."
   reference    : "800-53|SI-3,PCI-DSS|5.1.1,CCE|CCE-10076-8,PCI-DSS|5.1"
   see_also     : "https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/windows/CIS_Microsoft_Windows_7_Benchmark_v1.2.0.pdf"
   value_type   : POLICY_DWORD
   reg_key      : "HKU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments"
   reg_item     : "ScanWithAntiVirus"
   value_data   : 3
   reg_ignore_hku_users : "S-1-5-18,S-1-5-19,S-1-5-20"
```

I need the Map to be in a `<description,value_data>` format, regardless of whether anything comes after `value_data`  Eg:

```
Key: "1.9.56 Network security: Do not store LAN Manager hash value on next password changed."

Value: 1
```

Here is my current code for populating the Map with it's key values:

```
String descriptionString = Pattern.quote("description") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("info");


Pattern descriptionPattern = Pattern.compile(descriptionString);


Matcher descriptionMatcher = descriptionPattern.matcher(auditContentList.get(i));


while(descriptionMatcher.find())
{
      System.out.println("Key found ");
      customItemMap.put(descriptionMatcher.group(1),"");
}
```

Problem is I cant use two regexes simultaneously to populate the same index of the Map at any given time. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why not read the file line by line? Each line has pattern "name : value" so it'll be much easier.

Comment: I agree. regex is both under- and over-engineering for this problem

Answer (score 0):

for your sample data, maybe you should try this :

```
description.*?"(.*?)"[\s\S]*?value_data.*?(\d+)
```

i've test it [[here]](https://regex101.com/r/eS9wP9/3)

Comment: Unfortunately, group (2) does not populate correctly when the sample data is as follows:

Comment: type  : REGISTRY_SETTING
     description: "1.13.9 Screen Saver timeout = at most 900 seconds"
     info  : "This control defines the timeout setting for screen saver."
     solution : "Make sure 'Screen Saver timeout' is set to a Maximum of 900 seconds."
     reference : "CCE|CCE-10148-5,PCI-DSS|2.2.3,800-53|AC-1"
     see_also : "https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/windows/CIS_Microsoft_Windows_7_Benchmark_v1.2.0.pdf"
     value_type : POLICY_DWORD
     value_data : [MIN..900]